# Does a database column that has numbers need to be indexed?

Tags: sql, database, database-indexes, database-optimization

Suppose Bob has earned 107 points, Mary 105 points and John also 105 points. These numbers could change and are not unique.
Now I want to query and check the order, who is on top and who is on the bottom. Does that column that holds points need to be indexed ?

Comment: "need" no, but it's probably a good idea

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: Why don't you just create an index and compare performance? we can't do this for you. Here is a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441334/when-to-add-an-index-on-a-sql-table-field-mysql

Comment: It might be useful to know why you're thinking that an index wouldn't be useful here - what do you think is true of numeric columns that isn't true of other columns?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe  - I thought it could be redundant, just wanted a confirmation. However its a good idea to compare performance, it is exactly what I've read right before, as haytem adviced.

Comment: No one asks this kind of question when their system is running quickly so the answer is always "Yes".

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the database system used and the size (number of rows) of the table.

If the table is small enough and you're using MSSQL for example, [a table scan will be used](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224773%28v=sql.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (the entire table will be read into memory) and an index will be relatively useless.

Generally speaking, yes - the field [should be indexed if that is the column you'll be using to select or sort data](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/indexing-dos-and-don-ts).

Answer (score 1):

As a very general rule, I consider indexing columns that appear in the `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clauses of commonly executed queries.